# How to write yii2 contentOptions to have function and style?

Tags: php, yii2

I have my `contentOptions` in my GridView, which has the function. But besides that, I want the text to be text-aligned - center. How should I do that?

Here's my content options

```
'contentOptions' => function (Service $model) {
    $services = Service::getServices($model->services);
    if (BaseStringHelper::countWords($services) < 5) {
        return $services;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bootstrap's class for this:

```
return ['title' => $allPurposes, 'class' => 'text-center'];
```

or if you are not using Bootstrap you can use pure CSS:

```
return ['title' => $allPurposes, 'style' => 'text-align:center'];
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also tell me how to do that where is no return? I've updated my code. I also need to do that to `value`.

Comment: The same thing basically - just class alone - `return ['class' => 'text-center'];`

Comment: Somehow I get an error. I've updated my answer how I'm writing it into `value`

Comment: It should be written into contentOptions not value.

Comment: @Chinmay but besides contentOptions I'm asking him how to write it to `value` too, where there are some kind of title returns

Comment: @MKD there is `rowOptions` for this as well.

Comment: Im trying to write `'rowOptions'` style after the `'value'`, but it says that I'm setting unknown property.. Meh..

Comment: @MKD `contentOptions` is GridView's attribute but `value` is not - it's property of column.

Comment: use rowOptions before columns array and then check, since as @Bizley said it's Gridview's attribute.

Comment: It's still doesnt work... I'm doing something wrong... I just need the values to be text-aligned in center. rowOptions or `return ['title' => $allPurposes, 'style' => 'text-align:center'];` somehow doesn't work. I've updated my answer with the full code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
'contentOptions' => function (Client $model) {
    $allPurposes = ClientController::getClientIncomeSourceTitles($model->incomeSourceIdArray);
    if (BaseStringHelper::countWords($allPurposes) > 2) {
        return ['title' => $allPurposes, 'style' => 'text-align:center'];
    }
    return null;
}
```

For rowOptions:

```
'rowOptions' => function ($model, $index, $widget, $grid){
      return [ 'style'=>'text-align: center;' ];
    },
```

Comment: I've replaced your rowOptions with mine, but this also doesn't work. It says that I'm setting unknown property

Comment: Can you show your full gridview code .. rowOptions is a gridview property. I assume you are adding it to columns array.

Comment: I don't see any Gridview text or columns array?

Comment: Maybe could you move our discussion to chat? :(